# Calculating CRC of a WinRAR file - string of bytes in RAR file to correct message to be encoded

Tags: crc, rar, winrar

I know CRC calculation algorithm from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check). About structure of RAR file I read also in [Wikipedia](http://forensicswiki.org/wiki/RAR). At the very end they've written:

> The CRC is calculated using the standard polynomial 0xEDB88320. In
>   case the size of the CRC is less than 4 bytes, only the low order bytes
>   are used.

I have WinRAR 3.91, created exemplary archive and checked bytes, for example from 7 to 19, in this file, which are Archive Header (MAIN_HEAD). These bytes have the following values: 0x CF 90 73 00 00 0D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00, where first 2 bytes (0x90CF) is the HEAD_CRC (CRC of fields HEAD_TYPE to RESERVED2, i. e. following bytes: 0x 73 00 00 0D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00). Now how have I combine these values to get correct message, which have to be encoded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate CRC of a WinRAR file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34493385/how-to-calculate-crc-of-a-winrar-file)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear. How you combine them is to put the first two bytes before the other bytes.

If you are asking how to calculate 0x90cf from the following bytes, you use the standard ZIP CRC. You can use zlib for that, which is very likely already on your machine, accessible in some form from your standard libraries. The CRC-32 of `73 00 00 0D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` is `0x974290cf`. The low two bytes are in fact the first two bytes of the header, in little-endian order.

Comment: So for the following values: `73 00 00 0D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`, correct message, which have to be encoded, is `7300000D00000000000000`? I. e. it just enough to eat spaces between all these values? There's no need to, for example, change their order?

Comment: What? No! That (`73 00 00` ...) is a hexadecimal representation of the bytes in the file. You don't put the ASCII characters '7', '3', etc. in the file.  You put in the byte 0x73, or the byte 01110011 in binary.

Comment: OK, and now I explain, where this question from. I want to calculate CRC of above values, so in google I wrote "CRC calculator" and found this [site](https://ghsi.de/CRC/). There are 2 text boxes. To first of them it should write CRC polynomial as bit sequence, so I wrote there `11101101101110001000001100100000`, because it equals `0xEDB88320`. Next, to second of text boxes, it should write correct message as sequence of hex bytes, so I wrote there `73 00 00 0D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`. As result, I received `f7 3c 7d 18` than `97 42 90 cf`. Now I don't know, what's wrong.

Comment: That site is useless. It does not provide all the parameters required to specify a CRC. It's not just the polynomial. You also need to specify if the CRC is reflected or not, what the initial register value is, and what the final exclusive-or value is. Instead of trying to calculate CRCs on websites, do what I said and use zlib's `crc32()` routine.

Comment: I found this [site](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html), to text box wrote `73 00 00 0D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`, in Input type field selected Hex option and click to Calculate CRC button. As result, I received `97 42 90 cf`, so it looks this script calculates CRC correctly. That's just enough what I ment. @Mark Adler, thank you very much for help! I suggest to close this question.